# Google API search for folder by ID

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Is there a way to have the Google API search by ID?  I have tried a number of combinations of **q="id='FOLDER_ID'"** (I have been able to lookups by name, so I know my overall code is working), but I invariably get an error like this:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=id%3D%27FOLDER_ID%27&spaces=drive&fields=%2A&alt=json returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid Value', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'q'}]">

I haven't been able to find any documentation for the service.files().list() functions (all I found was "supported syntax" which is totally unhelpful), nor can I find an example for what I would have thought was a fairly basic lookup.

I'm doing this in python, but that's probably just secondary.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I am trying to use the google API to retrieve a folder's information using the folder's 32 character ID.  For example, if I have a folder https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1J5oHywhD9zDmOhgnfq6wdrrnyTJo6TX, I *should* be able to query using something like 'q="id = 1J5oHywhD9zDmOhgnfq6wdrrnyTJo6TX"' but it seems like "id" is not a valid query option.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the folder information from the folder ID.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

At the method of "Files: list", when the folder ID is used, the file list under the folder of folder ID can be retrieved. From your question, I thought that you might have wanted to use `'folderId' in parents` as the search query. In the current stage, `id` is not used in the search query. For example, when `name='folder name'` of the search query is used, the folder information can be retrieved. Unfortunately, the folder information cannot be directly retrieved from the folder ID using the method of "Files: list".

In this case, I think that you can use the method of "Files: get" can be used. When this is reflected to the script using googleapis for python, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
folderId = '###' # Please set the folder ID.
res = service.files().get(fileId=folderId, fields='*').execute()
print(res)
```

#### Note:

- If you want to achieve your goal using the method of "Files: list" and the folder ID, you can also use the folloing script. In this case, at first, the folder name is retrieved using the method of "Files: get" and the folder information is retrieved using the method of "Files: list". The search query of `q="name='" + res1['name'] + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"` is used for this. In this case, when the same folder names are existing in the Drive, the "Files: list" returns those folder information.

  ```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    folderId = '###' # Please set the folder ID.
    res1 = service.files().get(fileId=folderId).execute()
    res2 = service.files().list(q="name='" + res1['name'] + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false", fields='*').execute()
    print(res2)
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: That mostly worked for me.  Using "get" to gather the folder's information was definitely key.  The documentation for "get" says nothing about using it on folders.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach, though.  In one instance, I have a local folder with the same name as the folder I'm getting the contents of.  So, if I use this, res will wind up with the contents of *my* folder instead of the one I was actually looking at.

Fortunately, the solution to that is pretty simple (and is actually how I've been doing it so far): 

q=f"'{args.folder_id}' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"
or
q="'" + folderId + "' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"

Comment: @Phantom of Krankor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.